# When using Azure AD as an Identity Provider in Azure AD B2C, idp_access_token returned after signin causes error when passed to acquireTokenOnBehalfOf

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, msal.js

**Environment:**

- Node.js
- "@azure/msal-node": "^2.6.0"

**Short Version:**

When calling this:

```js
const response = await confidential_client_application.acquireTokenOnBehalfOf(on_behalf_of_request);
```

I am getting this error:

> Error obtaining token on behalf of user:
>
> ServerError: invalid_grant: 50013 - [2023-12-28 01:15:26Z]:
>
> AADSTS50013: Assertion failed signature validation.
>
> [Reason - Key was found, but use of the key to verify the signature
> failed.,
>
> Thumbprint of key used by client: 'E41DE************ED91', Found key
> 'Start=12/05/2023 17:16:57, End=12/05/2028 17:16:57',
>
> Please visit the Azure Portal, Graph Explorer or directly use MS Graph
> to see configured keys for app Id
> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'.
>
> Review the documentation at
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/deployments to determine the
> corresponding service endpoint and
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
> to build a query request URL, such as
> 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'].

The token I am passing through to `acquireTokenOnBehalfOf` is the `idp_access_token` returned after an Azure AD user signs in via Azure AD B2C.

**Long Version:**

**I have two tenants:**

**01)**  `Azure AD Home Tenant` (a 'Developer Program' tenant)

**02)**  `Azure AD B2C Tenant` (in a different tenant)

**I have four app registrations:**

In B2C Tenant:

**01)**  `B2C_SignIn_App_Registration`

In Azure AD Home Tenant:

**02)**  `InternalUser_M365_Access_App_Registration` (has Delegated permissions on Graph API)

**03)**  `ExternalUser_M365_Access_App_Registration` (has Application permissions on Graph API)

**04)**  `Admin_M365_Access_App_Registration` (has Application permissions on Graph API)

**Identity Provider:**

The 'home' Azure AD tenant is set up as an Identity Provider in the B2C tenant, which allows home tenant Azure AD users to login ('internal users'), as well as users created directly in Azure AD B2C ('external users').

**Home Tenant M365 Access Control:**

To control access to M365 resources in the home tenant:

- Internal users will be given a token from `InternalUser_M365_Access_App_Registration`
- External users will be given a token from `ExternalUser_M365_Access_App_Registration`
- The application itself will be given a token from `Admin_M365_Access_App_Registration`

Internal users access will therefore be limited by:

- The relevant app registration permissions
- Their own account permissions
- Application roles assigned to them from `InternalUser_M365_Access_App_Registration` and present in their token claims which can be used as control conditions in the app's code

External users access will therefore be limited by:

- The relevant app registration permissions
- Custom attributes in their user profiles that are present in their token claims which can be used as control conditions in the app's code

**Sign In Process:**

**01)**  Internal and External Users signin via `B2C_SignIn_App_Registration`

**02)**  After sign in, application code checks for the presence of the `idp_access_token` in the response.

**03)**  If that `idp_access_token` property is present, it indicates they are an `INTERNAL` user, otherwise they are an `EXTERNAL` user

**04)**  If they are an `INTERNAL` user, I am passing the `idp_access_token` through to an 'on-behalf-of' token request, eg:

```js
// these are the settings related to the app registration named `InternalUser_M365_Access_App_Registration`
msal_config = {
    auth: {
        clientId: process.env.APP_CLIENT_ID_InternalUser_M365_Access,
        clientSecret: process.env.APP_CLIENT_SECRET_InternalUser_M365_Access,
        authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.TENANT_ID_HOME_TENANT}`
    },
    system: {
        loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback(loglevel, message, containsPii) {
                console.log(message);
            },
            piiLoggingEnabled: false,
            logLevel: msal.LogLevel.Verbose,
        }
    }
};

on_behalf_of_request = {
    oboAssertion: idp_access_token,
    scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]   
};


// create msal instance
const confidential_client_application = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(msal_config);

// acquire token
const response = await confidential_client_application.acquireTokenOnBehalfOf(on_behalf_of_request);
```

The reason I am passing through the `idp_access_token` as the `oboAssertion` value, instead of the `accessToken` value, is because the response returned from the initial sign in has empty string values for `accessToken` and `tenantId` and an empty array for `scopes`.  However, it does have a value for `idp_access_token`.

**05)**  The `acquireTokenOnBehalfOf` request is returning the error message specified at the start of this post.

**06)**  The desired behaviour is that the error does not occur and that a token is returned to the internal user from the app registration named `InternalUser_M365_Access_App_Registration`.